# Prove that G is a complete graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I need help with this problem:
Let G be a graph such that, for all vertices a & b, the chromatic number of G - {a,b} = the chromatic number of G - 2.  Prove that G is a complete graph.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\chi(G\setminus\{a,b\}) = \chi(G)-2$ then $\{a,b\}$ is an edge of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $G$ is not complete, there are vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$ that are not connected by an edge. Take a minimal coloring of $G-\{u,v\}$, and show that at most one more color is needed for $G$.